# join three identical tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables with same columns but different number of rows (different each time).

```
   table A         table B      table C
   (NaRows)       (NbRows)      (NcRows)
  --------       ---------     ----------
ID name v1 v2  ID name v1 v2  ID name v1 v2
```

I want to create a table with all records (max of Na,Nb,Nc) without dublicates

```
     result of query 
-------------------------------------------------------------
A.ID    A.name    A.v1     A.v2     B.v1    B.v2     C.v1 C.v2
```

i try some JOINs without success. Please help me !

Comment: How are these tables related to each other?  What queries have you tried?  What did those return compared to what you want?

Comment: You should be more clear about what results you want.

Comment: Also some code would be nice. What did you try, how did it fail?

Comment: Are these tables related by ID? Like.. can I take an ID from table A and find it in Table B to find it's v1 and v2, and then take that same ID into Table C and find it's v1 and v2?

Comment: yes, they are related by ID. I want to join the rows from the three tables with the same ID . If one table hasn,t a coresponding row its values supposed to be zero

Comment: eg SELECT SUM(A.v1),SUM(A.v2),SUM(B.v1),SUM(B.v2),SUM(C.v1),SUM(C.v2) FROM TabbleA as A LEFT JOIN TableB as B on (A.ID=B.ID) LEFT JOIN TableC as C on (A.ID=C.ID)  In my case TableC has more rows than A, B. Is the condition (A.ID=.... that makes the resulting table to have only these rows that exist in A ? i' suppose yes. But how can join all the rows in this case ?

Comment: ID  name  v1    v2     ID name   v1    v2    ID  name   v1   v2
1    a   101   201     1   a    301   401     1    a   501   601
4    c   104   204     4   d    304   404     4    d   504   604
                       5   e    305   405     5    e   505   605
                                              6    f   506   606

i want this result
 
ID  name  v1    v2     B.v1  B.v2   C.v1  C.v2
1    a   101   201     301   401    501   601
4    d   104   204     304   404    504   604
5    e     0     0     305   405    505   605
6    f     0     0       0     0    506   606

Comment: If the tables are exactly the same, you could try union instead of join.

Comment: but, i don't want to append rows but append the columns

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.name,
    a.v1 AS a_v1,
    ...
    b.v1 AS b_v1, 
    ...
    c.v1 AS c_v1, 
    ...
FROM
    table_a as a,
    table_b as b,
    table_c as c
WHERE
    a.id = b.id
    AND b.id = c.id
```

will give you this result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
a.id   a.name   a_v1   a_v2   b_v1   b_v2   c_v1   c_v2
```

(you can name your resultset as you like)

Assertion: Every id exists in every table (otherwise you can use joins or union).

Comment: But it wouldn't work if tables have different number of rows, isn't so ?. If table a has Na rows, table b Nb and table c Nc, and eg Nb > Na > Nc, then i want the result table to have Nb rows where the Nath to Nbth have a_v1=0 and a_v2=0 since there aren't exist in table a, and the Ncth to Nbth rows have c_v1=0 and c_v2 =0 since there aren't exist in table c.